# Как анимировать canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas

По нажатию на кнопку квадрат изменяет позицию. Как сделать это перемещение плавным?
Может как то с помощью `requestAnimationFrame()` или `setInterval()`? 
Сам код:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    w = canvas.width = 200,
    h = canvas.height = 200,
    opts = {
        w: 80,
        h: 80,
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };

ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.fillRect(opts.x, opts.y, opts.w, opts.h);

document.onkeydown = control;

function control() {
    let speed = 20;
    ctx.clearRect(opts.x, opts.y, opts.w, opts.h)
    if(event.keyCode == 38) {   // up
        opts.y -= speed;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 40) {   // down
        opts.y += speed;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 37) {   // left
        opts.x -= speed;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 39) {   // down
        opts.x += speed;
    }
    ctx.fillRect(opts.x, opts.y, opts.w, opts.h)
}
```

```css
#canvas {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно управлять скоростью по нажатиям и отпусканиям клавиш и каждый кадр менять позицию на значение скорости, как-то так:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    w = canvas.width = 550,
    h = canvas.height = 175,
    speed = {x: 0, y: 0},
    time = 0,
    opts = {w: 80, h: 80, x: 0, y: 0};

ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.fillRect(opts.x, opts.y, opts.w, opts.h);

document.onkeydown = control.bind(0, 1);
document.onkeyup = control.bind(0, 0);

function control(v) {
    if (event.keyCode == 38) speed.y = -v; // up
    if (event.keyCode == 40) speed.y =  v; // down
    if (event.keyCode == 37) speed.x = -v; // left
    if (event.keyCode == 39) speed.x =  v; // down  
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw)

function draw (t) {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
  let dt = t - time
  opts.x += speed.x * dt/10;
  opts.y += speed.y * dt/10;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ctx.fillRect(opts.x, opts.y, opts.w, opts.h);
  time = t;
}
```

```css
#canvas {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Отличный ответ. Всегда читаю твои ответы с интересом. На мой взгляд нужно было указать какие клавиши жать  `keyCode == 38` не все поймут сразу, что это стрелки :-)